# Wireless adapter considered a modem

Tags: wireless-networking, modem

Is a wireless (Wifi) adapter considered a modem? I've never heard it explicitly called a modem but it seems to fit the definition since it's converting radio waves to a digital signal.

Comment: Some WiFi adapters (especially ones targeted for use with MCUs rather than PCs) have a serial (i.e. UART) electrical interface and an AT command interface.  The AT command interface originated from Hayes dial-up phone modems.  From the software perspective, such a WiFi adapter functions a lot like a phone modem.  Hence the association of WiFi adapter and modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *contains* a modem component since it must modulate and demodulate digital signals to and from analog signals, but it does not contain the control circuitry classically associated with a modem peripheral.